# problema con flutter Android license status unknown

Tags: flutter

recurro aquí porque la verdad no tengo ni idea como solucionarlo,
Probé con todo, reinstalando Andriod Studio, desintalando instalando el Andriod SDK tools (obsolete)
reinstalando java incluso me salto una actualización de flutter y nada [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy aprendiendo flutter y llevare menos de un mes con ello, agradezco si me podrían dar una mano

Variables de enterno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me da por consolta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no has aceptado todas las licencias de Android.
Se soluciona fácilmente mediante el flutter doctor de la siguiente manera.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Asegúrate de tener flutter correctamente añadido al PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve este mismo problema cuando empece a desarrollar, creo que intentaste todo lo que yo intente.

No se si ayude lo que te voy a decir, no se preocupe por ese error si esta en una etapa de aprendizaje. He desarrollado por un tiempo en flutter y ese error nunca me ha afectado para desarrollar.

Saludos.

Pd: Según hasta donde llegue y segui tiene que ver con la versión de java.
Este hilo puede orientarte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758849/flutter-io-android-license-status-unknown#comment103789407_51644766

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no puedo emular in dispositivo en mi pc (simplemente tardo demasiado en levantarlo porque es un procesador viejo, incluso con sdd) y lo hago que es emularlo en mi dispositivo pero se queda "trabado" por decirlo asi a la hora de apretar F5 y no avanza con la depuracion o instalacion o lo haga cuando lo hago correr en mi andriod

Answer (score 0):

lo Solucione descargando java la version 8, no se porque pero con las nuevas no funciona, solo con la 8 y agregando el path a las variables de enterno, luego el comando flutter doctor --android-licenses y listo